# Facebook Graph API: Get ad ID based on CTA link

Tags: facebook, graph

10k ft level: I want to retrieve an FB ad ID based on the ad's call-to-action URL.

I have a use case where given a specific page URL on our site, we would locate a matching facebook ad that links back to that page (we create ads for a specific type of page).

Our current workaround is to save the AD ID manually at time of creation as a data attribute on the page and then query the page for the ID.  The new use case is to obtain the ID by matching the AD's CTA URL to the page URL (since the ad points to the page) and use the resulting match to return the ID.

So far:
I can request an array of all AD IDs.  From that I can obtain each AD's object_story_id.  A new query can then be generated for each AD using object story ID to query it's link URL.

example:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/${act_id}/adcreatives/?&fields=${[object_story_id]}&access_token=${token}
```

this returns something like this:

```
  "data": [
    {
      "object_story_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    },
    {
      "object_story_id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx_xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "id": "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  ],
  "paging": {
    "cursors": {
      "before": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
      "after": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    }
  }
```

I could then iterate through the IDs to make a new query for the links(I can't show output at this time, as apparently my token doesn't have proper permissions):

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v3.2/${object_story_id}/?fields=${[link]}&access_token=${token}
```

This is less than ideal, as I have to create a while loop for all ads and then a new request for each object story ID.

I am looking for ideas/insight into how I can do this with a single nested request, where I pass the page URL to the request and it returns the AD ID of the AD with the same CTA url.  Baring that, are there any other single graph calls that would return all AD CTA URLs and IDs?

Thanks.

Comment: You should probably be able to achieve that using Field Expansion syntax, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced#fieldexpansion

Comment: Should that not work, you can at least make it a batch request, to save on the most costly part of API calls, the HTTP request, https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/making-multiple-requests